# Why won't this C array initialization compile under g++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, initialization

HI all
I have this code taken from a C project. I am not able to compile it in any way under g++.

What can I do with this?

```
 enum EnumIndexID{
       ID_VALUE_A=2,
       ID_VALUE_B=2
 }

 struct newtype {
     enum MyEnumID eid;
     const char *name;
} table[] = {
     [ID_VALUE_A] = { MyEnumA, "ID_MSG_HeartbeatReq"},
     [ID_VALUE_B] = { MyEnumB, "ID_MSG_HeartbeatReq"},
};
```

Comment: If this is pure C code I don't think the C++ tag belongs there.

Comment: You have not mentioned what are the compilation errors are you receiving?

Comment: Are ID_VALUE_A and ID_VALUE_B intended to be the same? GCC doesn't seem to have any problem with that and just uses the last initializer, though.

Comment: Given the debate on some of the answers below, it would be very useful if you could be more specific about your compiler. Version number and platform would be particularly helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following compiles fine as C99 (note: it's not valid as C89):

```
enum MyEnumID {
    MyEnumA, MyEnumB
};

enum EnumIndexID{
    ID_VALUE_A=2,
    ID_VALUE_B=2
};

struct newtype {
    enum MyEnumID eid;
    const char *name;
} table[] = {
    [ID_VALUE_A] = { MyEnumA, "ID_MSG_HeartbeatReq"},
    [ID_VALUE_B] = { MyEnumB, "ID_MSG_HeartbeatReq"},
};

int main() { return 0; }
```

**EDIT**: others have noted that `ID_VALUE_A` and `ID_VALUE_B` are the same value, namely 2. That's probably a bug in your code. However, gcc accepts this.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: As it turns out, it also doesn't compile as C++ which is explicitly stated in the GCC docs.

Comment: So the correct GCC setting would be either -std=gnu99 or std=c99.

Comment: you are right that this is probably a bug here, but it is standard conforming. AFAIR it is the last initialization that wins.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure that your compiler supports the [Designated Initializer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) syntax?

g++ does not.
From that hyperlink:

> Standard C89 requires the elements of an initializer to appear in a fixed order, the same as the order of the elements in the array or structure being initialized.
>
> In ISO C99 you can give the elements in any order, specifying the array indices or structure field names they apply to, and GNU C allows this as an extension in C89 mode as well. **This extension is not implemented in GNU C++**.

Comment: It is implemented in good old Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 at least. Maybe you are using the wrong compiler settings?

Comment: Dev-C++ uses the mingw port of GCC - perhaps Designated Initializers are supported in the port? He doesn't go into specifics on the compiler or his environment. I still suspect this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon after the first enum definition.

**Edit**

Also, [it turns out that this syntax is supported by GCC but isn't supported by G++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing semicolon after the `enum` definition, the `table[]` declaration <strike>is not syntactically correct</strike> won't compile on G++:

```
struct newtype {
     enum MyEnumID eid;
     const char *name;
} table[] = {
     { MyEnumA, "ID_MSG_HeartbeatReq"},
     { MyEnumB, "ID_MSG_HeartbeatReq"},
};
```

**EDIT**: Today i've learned about designated initialization.

Comment: It is syntactically correct and compiles fine in G++ after adding that semicolon (and a definition of MyEnumID, of course). I don't quite understand how the compiler handles duplicate indexes in a designated initializer, though.

Comment: Sorry, I got it a bit wrong. It is apparently supported by GCC, but not by G++. Since it was a pure C code I didn't use G++ at first.

Comment: Yeap, me too, I've just learned about designated initializers.

Comment: Isn't G++ set to compile as "GCC" by default? Ie "compile as C99 minus some, plus some GNU fluff". I'm fairly certain it should compile with the default compiler settings.

Comment: Nope, `g++` is the C++ compiler, a different one from `gcc`.

Comment: @Lundin, I have tried it with MinGW G++ 4.5.0 and it just gives a bunch of irrelevant error messages about lambda expressions.

Answer (score -1):

well you need at least an entry point:

```
int main() {
.... lots of other code ...
}
```

Comment: You only need it for linking (and only if your project is an application), not for compiling.